# notation for excluding an element from a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I'm working on a question wherein I need to show that $y=Sup\, x_{n}$ but without the element $x_{1}$. Can I just write $y=Sup\, (x_{n}/x_{1})$?

Comment: No. I would write $y = \sup_{n \neq 1} x_n$.

Comment: or $y=\sup\{x_n\mid n\neq 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such a thing would be written $$\sup\{x_2,x_3,...\},$$ but other options are $$\sup\{x_n:n\geq 2\}$$  or $$\sup_{n\geq 2} x_n.$$
The notation $$\sup(\{x_n\}\setminus\{x_1\})$$ is valid, but I've never seen it.

Comment: thanks, Ill try one of these ways.

Comment: The last variation (the unseen one) sometimes expresses something else if $x_1$ occurs at other positions as well.